# как применить валидацию к динамически изменяющимся элементам?

Tags: javascript, jquery

при нажатии на кнопку save я должен проверить заполнены ли поля или нет, элементы добавляються динамически при нажатии на кнопку add element - проблема в том что если после нажатия на кнопку save добавить ещё блок а потом ещё раз нажать на save то валидация не применяеться к новому блоку. Как можно это исправить?

```
html:
<button class="js-add-element">Add element</button>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="block"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="block"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
<button class="js-save">save</button>

js:
$(".js-add-element").click(function() {
    $(".wrapper").append('<div class="block"><input type="text"></div>');
});

$(".js-save").click(function() {
    $(".block").each(function(){
      var inputVal = $(this).find("input").val();
      if (inputVal == "") {
         $(this).addClass("error");
      } else {
         $(this).removeClass("error");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".js-add-element").click(function() {
  $(".wrapper").append('<div class="block"><input type="text"></div>');
});

$(".js-save").click(function() {
  $(".block").each(function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).find("input").val();
    if (inputVal == "") {
      $(this).addClass("error");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("error");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="js-add-element">Add element</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="block"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="js-save">save</button>
```

Comment: я опечатку сделал в вопросе не написав Input, я в вопросе поправил, но это не решает проблемы дело в том что each не видет после нажатия на кнопку новые блоки

Comment: @DimaVleskov Он и старые не видит - у Вас опечатки в слове `function`.